# Next.js: 'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Why do I get error in this line?

```
<Provider store={store}>{getLayout?(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider>
```

```
(parameter) Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, {}> & NextPageWithLayout
'Component' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<{}, any, any>' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass'.
      Type 'Component<{}, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
        The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
          Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/@types/styled-jsx/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactNode'.
            Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
```

Full component:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { ReactElement, ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { setAuthnRes } from '../slices/User'
import { store } from '../store'
import '../styles/globals.scss'
import { baseURL } from '../utils/baseURL'

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
    getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
    Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENVIRONMENT ?? 'local',
    true
)

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
    const dispatch = store.dispatch
    const authnUserResp = store.getState().authnUser?.resp

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!authnUserResp) {
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'me',
                headers: { crossDomain: true },
            }).then((res) => {
                dispatch(setAuthnRes(res.data))
            })
        }
    })

    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>)

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>{getLayout?(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider> // <--- HERE
    )
}

export default MyApp
```

I upgraded Next.js to the most recent one, maybe that causes some issue?

```
"next": "12.1.0",
```

Do I need both normal and TypeScript reference in `package.json`, do you know?

```js
"@types/next": "^9.0.0",
"next": "12.1.0",
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304#issuecomment-1092563688

Comment: I could be wrong but aren't you using the ternary operator wrong? `<Provider store={store}>{getLayout?(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider>` after the `Component` you're not providing the else case. `getLayout ? <Component {...pageProps} /> : null`

Comment: The error was the backend was not operational, and frontend raise strange errors. Server side rendering was not able to get data. So error is totally different what I was expecting.

Comment: I had the same problem, I solved it by updating the packages to the versions: ```next@latest```, ```react@latest```, ```react-dom@latest```

Comment: yarn add @types/react@latest @types/react-dom@latest --dev

Comment: This is not a duplicate, and the answer in the other SO post is not correct given this context. I'm really sick of trigger happy SO mods going around marking everything as dupes. I'm sure that's gratifying for them, makes them feel productive and useful to the community, but the behavior needs to stop.

Answer (score 23):

I fixed that by deleting yarn.lock file. There was issues with types across packages versions.

"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
"@types/react": "17.0.30"

Comment: Is this the correct way of fixing this issue , https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304#issuecomment-1092563688 how about this , how can we use this solution ?

Comment: Not sure about the "preinstall" line but deleting the yarn.lock file and running "yarn" solved the problem for me.

Comment: for those that use `yarn` just need to add the

"resolutions": {}

to the package.json

so, `npm-force-resolutions` isn't needed.

Comment: The above didn't work for me and neither did the `package.json` resolution.

Comment: Had to delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` then run `yarn` and it worked for NextJS 12 => 13 upgrade

Comment: Deleting both `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and then running `yarn` helped me as well.

Answer (score 16):

Nothing to "seriously" recommend, but I was able to workaround the error by omitting types:

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const AnyComponent = Component as any;
  return <AnyComponent {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Comment: I get that Typescript people don't like `any` but seriously, this error messed with me real bad, I was completely stuck, searched for hours, tried the same kind of solution but with `as JSX.Element` and it didn't work. This is the only thing that worked for me so thank you @camposer