# react 'component' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am running into error for 2 days, where I get error that my react cannot be used as a JSX component.

Full error :

> 'ExportTemplateModal' cannot be used as a JSX component.
> Its element type 'ReactElement<any, any> | Component<Omit<Subtract<IExportTemplateModalProps, WithTranslationProps>, keyof WithTranslation<...>> & WithTranslationProps, any, any> | null' is not a valid JSX element.
> Type 'Component<Omit<Subtract<IExportTemplateModalProps, WithTranslationProps>, keyof WithTranslation<N, undefined>> & WithTranslationProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Element | ElementClass | null'.
> Type 'Component<Omit<Subtract<IExportTemplateModalProps, WithTranslationProps>, keyof WithTranslation<N, undefined>> & WithTranslationProps, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'ElementClass'.
> The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
> Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.

here is the component which I get this error for:

```js
export class ExportTemplateModal extends React.Component<
  IExportTemplateModalProps,
  IExportTemplateModalState
  > {
  private _subscriptionTimer: number = 0;

  constructor(props: IExportTemplateModalProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...initialState };
    this._handleClose = this._handleClose.bind(this);
    this._handleExport = this._handleExport.bind(this);
    this._handleStatusUpdate = this._handleStatusUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  public async componentDidMount() {
    const { projectSuppliers } = this.props;
    const supplierMap = constructSupplierMap(projectSuppliers);
    const allPartnerIDs = projectSuppliers.map(supplier => supplier.supplierId).filter(Boolean);
    const partnerInfo = await loadPartnerInfo(allPartnerIDs);
    this.setState({ partnerInfo, supplierMap });
  }

  public render() {
    const { open, projectSuppliers } = this.props;
    const { status } = this.state;
    const { Status } = status;
    const suppliers = addGenericSupplier(projectSuppliers);

    return (
      <Modal
        bodySpacingInset="large"
        data-id="quote-export-template-modal-content"
        open={open}
        onClose={this._handleClose}
        title="Export template"
        scrollContainer="modal"
        width="35rem"
      >
        <div id="quote-export-template-modal-content">
          {Status === 'NOT_STARTED' && this._renderSupplierSelection(suppliers)}
          {Status !== 'NOT_STARTED' && this._renderExportStatus()}
        </div>
        {Status === 'NOT_STARTED' && (
          <ModalFooter>
            <Row alignmentVertical="center" alignmentHorizontal="right" widths="fit">
              <Button className="mr3" type="secondary" onClick={this._handleClose}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button type="primary" onClick={this._handleExport}>
                Export
              </Button>
            </Row>
          </ModalFooter>
        )}
      </Modal>
    );
  }

 
}

export default withTranslation()(ExportTemplateModal);
```

here is the package.json, I have tried to change the react version and react-dom and ran `npm install` but it did not work. I am not sure where I am doing wrong. If I export `export default Component as any` it stops complaining but I do not know if that is the fix because in my unit tests I get another error which it complains about the React wrapper, this is the error => `Error: ReactWrapper::state() can only be called on class components`

```js
"dependencies": {
   "@amzn/pb-central-gql-schema": "*",
   "@amzn/pb-central-ui-components": "^1.0.0",
   "@hookform/resolvers": "^1.3.7",
   "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
   "@testing-library/dom": "^8.13.0",
   "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
   "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.7",
   "emotion": "^10.0.27",
   "is-hotkey": "^0.1.8",
   "is-url": "^1.2.4",
   "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^2.0.0",
   "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
   "lodash.differenceby": "^4.8.0",
   "lodash.escaperegexp": "^4.1.2",
   "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
   "lodash.isempty": "^4.4.0",
   "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
   "lodash.set": "^4.3.2",
   "lodash.sortby": "^4.7.0",
   "lodash.uniqueid": "^4.0.1",
   "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.107.0",
   "react-hook-form": "^6.15.7",
   "react-i18next": "^11.18.3",
   "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
   "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
   "slate": "^0.60.8",
   "slate-history": "^0.59.0",
   "slate-react": "^0.60.8"
 },
 "peerDependencies": {
   "@amzn/meridian": "*",
   "@amzn/meridian-tokens": "*",
   "react": "^16.13.0",
   "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
   "date-fns": "^2.16.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@amzn/brazil": "*",
   "@amzn/meridian": "*",
   "@amzn/meridian-tokens": "*",
   "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
   "@babel/helper-validator-identifier": "7.10.4",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
   "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
   "@babel/runtime": "7.4.5",
   "@sheerun/mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.3",
   "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.26",
   "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.26",
   "@storybook/addon-info": "5.3.21",
   "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.0.26",
   "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.26",
   "@storybook/addons": "^6.0.26",
   "@storybook/react": "^6.0.26",
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
   "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
   "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
   "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.7",
   "@types/history": "^4.7.8",
   "@types/is-url": "^1.2.4",
   "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
   "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.6",
   "@types/lodash.differenceby": "^4.8.6",
   "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.6",
   "@types/lodash.isempty": "^4.4.6",
   "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.5",
   "@types/lodash.set": "^4.3.6",
   "@types/lodash.sortby": "^4.7.6",
   "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
   "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
   "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
   "@types/storybook-react-router": "^1.0.1",
   "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.4.0",
   "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.4.0",
   "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
   "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
   "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
   "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.19",
   "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
   "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
   "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",
   "eslint": "7.11.0",
   "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
   "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.1.0",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
   "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
   "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
   "globby": "^8.0.1",
   "history": "^4.10.1",
   "husky": "^4.3.8",
   "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
   "jest": "^24.9.0",
   "jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
   "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.2",
   "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
   "jest-when": "^3.2.1",
   "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
   "prettier": "^2.2.1",
   "prettier-plugin-organize-imports": "^1.1.1",
   "react-to-typescript-definitions": "^1.2.0",
   "storybook-react-router": "^1.0.8",
   "typescript": "^4.2.4",
   "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
 },
 "npm-pretty-much": {
   "publishDir": "",
   "runRelease": "always"
 },
 "husky": {
   "hooks": {
     "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
   }
 },
 "lint-staged": {
   "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
   "src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,css,md}": "prettier --write"
 }
```

I have tried:

- running `npm i react@18 react-dom@18 @types/react@18 @types/react-dom@18`
- removing node_module and npm install again
- played around with imports

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by that code. Where do `projectSuppliers` and `options` come from, and what do you do with `selectedSupplier` once you've declared it? What does `this.setState({...});` do?

Comment: @Andy the same component works in other repo/packages.

Comment: There’s a lot of code that’s not being shown here

Comment: @Adam I have updated the code, now you can see the full component. but keep in mind that this component works fine in other places, which makes me think that the issue is not the component

Comment: I also added the full error if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the resolution:

Solved the issue as follows:

Added the following to package.json file

`"resolutions": { "@types/react": "17.0.14", "@types/react-dom": "17.0.14" },`

add the following to the to 'scripts' session in package.json file:

`"preinstall": "npm install --package-lock-only --ignore-scripts && npx npm-force-resolutions"`

Comment: I just needed to add @types/react-dom and reinstall node_modules, similar to some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71809903/next-js-component-cannot-be-used-as-a-jsx-component